# CMake Gui: Changing .lib and .dll name

Tags: cmake

I want the CMake Gui to Change the .lib and .dll names with defined postfixes like:

- _vs12_d64(_omp_off)

If this is not possible via the CMake Gui how to do this in the CMake file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfixes can be added using `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` and `CMAKE_RELEASE_POSTFIX` depending on `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.
You can either set these values globally or use [`set_target_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) to change it only for specific targets.

You need to do this in the corresponding CMakeLists.txt file, see the following example:

```
project(test)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_debug_postfix")
set(CMAKE_RELEASE_POSTFIX "_release_postfix")
add_library(test test.c)
```

This will generate **libtest_debug_postfix.a**.

Comment: and is it possible to add other postfixes and concatenate them, like compiler used or build with omp on or build with opencl on?

Comment: yes of course, you just need to build the postfix string using CMake depending on the compiler etc. http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables lists available internal variables you could use.